# Trouble Accessing Set Context in Collection2 to Display Invalid Keys on CLIENT

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I am using Collection2 for form insert and validation.  It works great.

My only issue using the context to access the keys for presenting errors back to the user on the client.

I have the following code:

```
Common.coffee

Schemas = {}
Schemas.Journal = new SimpleSchema
    goal:
        type: String
        label: "Related Goal"
        max: 200
    description:
        type: String
        label: "Comment"
        max: 200
    likes:
        type: Number
        label: "Likes"
        min: 0
    createdBy:
        type: String
        max: 50
    createdAt:
        type: Date
        label: "Created At"

Journal.attachSchema(Schemas.Journal)
journalContext = Schemas.Journal.namedContext("insertForm")

On Client:
    Template.journalForm.events
        'submit #newEntryForm': (event) ->
            text = event.target.text.value
            Meteor.call("newJournalEntry", Session.get("activeGoal"), text)             

On Server as a Method:
        'newJournalEntry': (goalId, text) ->
            Journal.insert
                goal: goalId
                description: text
                createdAt: new Date()
                createdBy: Meteor.userId()
                likes: 0
                {validationContext: "insertForm"}, (error, result) ->
                    if error
                        console.log error.invalidKeys
                    else
                        console.log "#{result} added to Journal collection."
```

The validation works correctly on the server and when insert is denied I see the correct messages via terminal, but **calling the validation context ON THE CLIENT always gives back an empty array. []**

Either of the following work on the server, but if I try these on the client they are empty:

```
Schemas.Journal.namedContext("insertForm").invalidKeys()
```

or

```
error.invalidKeys
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried a few more tries at the syntax ON THE CLIENT.  Same empty array result.  Here are the attempts:

```
Schemas.Journal.namedContext().invalidKeys()
journalContext.invalidKeys()
Schemas.Journal.namedContext("insertForm").invalidKeys()
```

Comment: I can't see where you validate on the client. Not validating on the client = empty context on the client. Just turn your method into a client/server method (instead of a server-only method) and it should work.

Comment: @steph643 - Thank you.  I copied my server method and added it as a Meteor.method on the client as well.  Now it works!  However, is that ok to have the method on the client?  I always thought you wanted these insert commands on the server.  Also it seems weird to have duplicate code.  I am likely missing something on the best way to set this up.

Comment: Most of the time, methods should be both client/server. This pattern is called "latency compensation" and is one of the main Meteor strength. There is no code duplication, as the same code is used both on server and client.

Comment: Thanks - Added the single method in common and it's good to go!